# How to Tag Data Driven Template Tests in Robot Framework

Tags: tags, robotframework, testrail

I have numerous data driven tests so that I can run the same test with multiple rows of data, which works well.  However, we also use TestRail and link RF tests to TestRail via a Tag on the RF test.  Currently I'm only tagging one TestRailID per template.  Eg:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Verify Registering For An Event with each CC Type
  [Template]  Register For An Event with a Credit Card
  [Tags]    TestRailID=1211  Smoke    
  ${cc_intl}   ${personInfo}  ${visaCardInfo}
  ${cc_intl}   ${personInfo}  ${masterCardInfo}
  ${cc_intl}   ${personInfo}  ${americanCardInfo}
  #etc
```

I would like each row of data to have a unique tag for the TestRailID.  How can I add a tag for each data row in the above example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple solution would be to modify your template to accept a tag as one of the arguments, then call [set tags](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Tags) within your keyword.

Example:

```
*** Keywords ***
Register For An Event with a Credit Card
    [Arguments]  ${tag}  ${personInfo}  ${cardInfo}
    set tags  ${tag}
    log  personInfo: ${personInfo} cardInfo: ${cardInfo}

*** Test Cases ***
Verify Registering For An Event with each CC Type
  [Template]  Register For An Event with a Credit Card
  [Tags]    TestRailID=1211  Smoke    
  TestRailID=1  person one    visa
  TestRailID=2  person two    mastercard
  TestRailID=3  person three  american express
```

Comment: Hi. I tried testing this and what happens is that if one of the scenarios fail, all tags are logged as failed even if the other two did succeed. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @MKSpan: there is  probably no solution; tags are associated with test cases, not individual parts of a test.