# How to set tag for Robot Framework in data driver tests?

Tags: tags, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I am trying to add a tag in accordance with the documentation
https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver

Here is my example:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template  Template

*** Test Cases ***  ${first}  ${second}  [Tags]  [Documentation]
Test1               xxx       111        123 
Test2               yyy       222        126 
Test3               zzz       333        124 

*** Keywords ***
Template
    [Arguments]  ${first}  ${second}
    Should be true  ${TRUE}
```

But in this case, I got the error:

```
Keyword 'Template' expected 2 arguments, got 3.
```

I also saw this solution: [How to Tag Data Driven Template Tests in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631160/how-to-tag-data-driven-template-tests-in-robot-framework)

But in this case, I can not run a particular test by using `-i test_tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.

You can also set default tags like so:

```
*** Settings ***
Default Tags    smoke
```

All test cases that do not have their own tags will receive tags defined as default tags.

Or you can use forced tags:

```
Force Tags      req-882
```

All test cases in a file will receive such tags.

However, your example contains yet another problem. You're passing 3 arguments to your Template keyword, you have 3 columns of arguments in your test case table. It should be like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***  ${first}    ${second}
Test1               xxx       111
Test2               yyy       222
Test3               zzz       333
```

So the whole working example:

```
*** Settings ***
Default Tags    smoke
Test Template  Template

*** Test Cases ***  ${first}    ${second}
Test1               xxx       111
Test2               yyy       222
Test3               zzz       333

*** Keywords ***
Template
    [Arguments]  ${first}  ${second}
    Should be true  ${TRUE}
```

when I run `$ robot --include smoke test.robot`, I get:

[image]

and when I run `$ robot --exclude smoke test.robot`, I get:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want to set tags per test case, the syntax is:

```
*** Test Cases ***  ${first}    ${second}
Test1               xxx       111
    [Tags]    smoke
Test2               yyy       222
Test3               zzz       333
```

in which case, only Test1 will be executed when you issue `$ robot -i smoke test.robot`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I need to add different tags for each test.

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer, so it fits what you're looking for.